# How to clip an Openlayers OSM Background to a Vector Boundary?

Tags: qgis, raster, openstreetmap, clip

I'm new to QGIS. In my project i have two layers: one is my vector (city boundaries) and the other is the OSM (obtained with the plugin). How can I cut the OSM along the edges of the vector? I want to obtain only a region of the map, to save it as an image.

Comment: Please be more specific: Did you use the OSM plugin to download OSM vector data or did you use the Openlayers plugin to download rendered OSM tiles?

Comment: I downloaded a shapefile with vector layers from a government site. Then I used the OSM plugin to insert a background map inside my vector. Is it possible? Because at the moment I have the vector and beside him all the map from OpenStreetMap, even if i want only an area.
Sorry for my bad english and for my noobness.

Comment: From your other comment, I assume you used the **Openlayers** plugin. The **Openstreetmap** plugin loads OSM vector data, but needs a lot of handwork to get a good looking background map.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly what the OP asked, but going from AndreJ's answer, I get this error: ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero. What does this mean and how can I get around this?

Comment: Please don't ask a question in an answer, if you are having a similar problem then please ask a new question and reference this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This way it works:

1. unselect your vector data, to show only the Openstreetmap background
2. `File -> Save as Image`
3. Load the image as raster, set EPSG:3857 as CRS
4. Delete the Openstreetmap background layer
5. `Raster -> Projection -> Reproject`, choosing EPSG:3857 as source CRS and the CRS of the vector data as target CRS, saving as Geotiff under a different name, adding that to the canvas
6. Remove the image loaded in step 3
7. `Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper` check `Mask layer` with the vector data, and add the result to the canvas
8. Remove the unclipped raster layer from step 5

---

**EDIT**

If you want the clipping for all zoom levels, see my answer here:

[How do I clip OSM basemap with a polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73048/how-do-i-clip-osm-basemap-with-a-polygon)

Comment: It works, thanks! Two more questions:
1) there is a way to improve the image quality? If I zoom I can't read the name of the cities in the map
2) cutting along the boundaries is not perfect, it not match for some millimeters. Is a problem of CRS?

Comment: I solved the problem with the CRS, it was my fault when i select them during the reprojection. Still have the problem with the quality of the image.

Comment: You can zoom further in, and make several images in step 2. You have to build a virtual raster to get them all together before clipping. Or follow the link to an earlier question in my expanded answer.