# Creating Offline Maps using QGIS and OpenStreetMap?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am working with QGIS 2.10.1, having only little knowledge with the software so far.

I am mapping certain findspots in northern Bavaria and use the OCMlandscape map as basemap. Everything works fine as long as I am in the internet, but I need the whole thing offline.

The Offline plugin `Database->offline editing->convert into an offline project` doesn't work. The program tells me "unable to open database file".

Afterwards I tried to download the part via `Vektor->Open Street Map -> Download Data`, but the download gets always interrupted.

I then downloaded the Northern Bavaria map from geofabric (file: .osm). With Vektor -> Open Street Map -> topology imported from XML and afterwards ->topology export to spatial line I get a huge set of data and a blue points or lines or polygons that has the shape of northern bavaria but doesn't look like a topographic card :)

How do I know which tags I have to export?

Or do you have any idea how to get this ground map offline?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80488/how-to-clip-an-openlayers-osm-background-to-a-vector-boundary) may help out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, that is a great emergency solution :)!