# Using polygon fill effect to desaturate underlying base-map imagery in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, visualisation, map-drawing, fill

In QGIS 3.12 I'm tying to use a draw effect with a polygon layer (that has an inverse fill) that will desaturate imagery underneath it, while keeping it's brightness the same. The objective is to have a grey-scale imagery outside of the boundaries, while retaining the full saturation within it.

What I have pictured here is my best attempt so far, which is not quite it.

[image: attempt_1]

How can I improve it?

Comment: What is wrong with your best attempt so far?

Comment: Do you have access to a greyscale image?

Comment: @PolyGeo The fill in the picture tones the background imagery down a bit, but it just whitens it. What I'm hoping to get is a a result that renders it completely grey-scale, without fading it.

Comment: @BERA The imagery I have pictured is from Google, via the QuickMapServices plugin. I can turn the background image into a grey-scale, but it would affect the whole area. I'm looking to keep the inside of the polygon full color, with the outside grey-scale

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Do you need it in map or layout view? I know of a solution in layout view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS 3.24 there is now a group blending mode that will allow this effect.

1. Duplicate your satellite imagery layer
2. Make one of the layers grayscale
3. Create a Group with your polygon above your color imagery
4. With the group selected in Layer Styling check **Render Layers as a Group**
5. In the layer styling of your polygon layer set the **Layer Rendering Blend Mode** to **Mask Below**

[image: mask below settings]

As long as your clipping group is above your grayscale image you will get the effect of a desaturated mask even as the satellite imagery updates on zoom.

[image: layers and result]