# Visually clipping a search area (MCE) (QGIS)

Tags: qgis

I have some search areas to refine using a variety of vector inputs. I can clip these to get my end product but it is a messy process. Is it possible to use blending modes to visually "knock out" unsuitable areas without actually doing the clipping?
Inputs are vector polygons, system is QGIS 2.8 Mac.

Comment: You could use something like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73048/how-do-i-clip-osm-basemap-with-a-polygon to mask the unwanted areas.

Comment: I don't want the areas to be white, I would like the base map visible beneath

Comment: In step 4, you can reduce the white from 100% to some kind of transparency.

Comment: "Subtract your polygon shapefile from that, and set the fill of the remaining polygon to 100% white."  ????? Doesn't help