# Can a mask layer filter out color, rendering the area covered by the mask into grayscale?

Tags: qgis, color, masking

Here I have a transparent mask layer which highlights an area of interest by making the basemap outside the area of interest a lighter color.

What I'd like to do is have the masking layer change the basemap to grayscale outside the area of interest. Is this possible?

[image]

The basemap is Bing Satellite. I'd rather not get into downloading the basemap, converting to raster, clipping the raster, etc. etc. I'm hoping for a graphic solution.

My question is related to and inspired by [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231623/can-i-use-a-polygon-to-show-a-wms-layer-inside-while-maintaining-transparency-ou#comment366187_231623).

Comment: I guess its not possible atm. Unfortunately there is no "Color" Layer blending Mode like GIMP has. That would be a nice feature request!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this with just the basemap in either QGIS or ArcGIS.  This is because you need to convert RGB values to Greyscale and basemaps do not give you access to the actual raster values.  So if you really want to do this, you probably need to get your hands on a raster that you can manipulate.